# Conditional and Existential Types on Translated Typescript Object

Tags: typescript, generics, existential-type, conditional-types

I hope this makes sense.

I'm trying to write a function that takes an object where each key equals a function and returns a function who's rest argument(s) are a translation of that object to [a key of the object, and the params of that key's function]

### My Code:

```js
export const useConfig =
  <T extends Record<string, (...a: any) => null>>(features: T) =>
  <O extends T, K extends keyof O>(...args: [K, ...Parameters<O[K]>][]): void =>
    void 0;

const config = useConfig({
  attr: (prop: 'id', val: string) => null,
  style: (prop: 'font', val: 'arial') => null,
});
```

### The Problem:

This `const t2 = config(['attr', 'font','']);` shouldn't work, it should:

1. complain that "font" is wrong.
2. After having defined "attr" as the first param, the second param should be typed against "prop:'id'" and the third against "val:string".

### R&D

1. I've been trying my best to figure out if this is an Existential Type issue (which I believe it is) but I can't make the connection
2. I know this is an issue of Conditional typing because if I create multiple generics for the returned function with a bunch of optional param, each assigned to each generic, it works. However, every time I try to figure out how to do this "dynamically" I seem to land on "Existential Types" and I go round and round.

Any help would be much appreciated. I feel like I'm just not getting something fundamental about the type system.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKV0Km) meet your needs?  Existential types are sort of "infinite unions", but in your case you probably only need finite unions (`keyof T` is `"attr" | "style"`) so you can just use unions directly.  If that works for you I can write up an explanation; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes and no. The "type checking" part is correct but the intellisense part is what I'm really after. `Parameters<T[K]>` can't just be a plain union of all the parameters of the functions. After defining "attr" as the first argument both "font" and "id" are being presented as options in the intellisense when only "id" should be suggested. So the first argument will always be ` "attr" | "style"` (as they are the keys of the object) but then the following options should be "conditionally typed" / narrowed to be only those of that keys function. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see "IntelliSense", "autocomplete", etc., listed anywhere in your question, so I'm a bit confused about why it doesn't meet your needs. Seems like a followup question since it's the next thing you ran into. The typing is correct: after defining `"attr"` as the first argument, the compiler will not accept `"font"` as the next argument, no matter what is being presented.  The fact that IntelliSense is somewhat confused or confusing with discriminated unions with multiple literal properties seems to be out of scope for the original question as stated.

Comment: `-?` is a [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers).

Comment: Note that your trouble with IntelliSense is an open issue in TypeScript, at [microsoft/TypeScript#38603](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38603). If you care about it you might want to go there and give it a  or describe why it's important to you.  But right now it's not something I can really fix for you.  *Maybe* there's a workaround, but that is definitely out of scope for the question as originally asked. Consider either accepting the suggestion and opening a new question for IntelliSense, or [edit]ing the question to specify your requirements around IntelliSense.

Comment: [Possible workaround for IntelliSense issue](https://tsplay.dev/WKV0gm).  Let me know how to proceed here.

Comment: That works!!! I get it. Much appreciated!

Comment: Post your answer and I'll select it as the answer asap.

Comment: Sure, I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  Might be in a few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows I'll call the operation in question, turning a key `K` (which `extends keyof T` for some suitable `T` whose values are all function types) into the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `[K, ...Parameters<T[K]>]`, "parameterizing" `K`, or a "parameterization" of `K`.

Conceptually you want the return type of `useConfig` to be a function which accepts a variadic number of arguments, where each argument is a parameterization of *some* key in `keyof T`.  You don't really want to know which argument is a parameterization of which key, just that each one corresponds to *some* key.  This use of "some" is indeed a hint that the kind of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) quantification you'd need here is [existential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) instead of the "normal" universal quantification.  You can think of normal, universal generics as [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) over every acceptable type, while existential generics are *unions* over every acceptable type.

And here, since "every acceptable type" is just the single members of `keyof T`, then you can represent this union directly.  All you want to do is *distribute* the parameterization operation over the union in `K` to make a new union.

If you want to distribute an operation over keylike types, you can use a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and then immediately [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  If you have a key set `KS` and you want to distribute the operation `F<K>` over it, you can write that like `{[K in KS]: F<K>}[KS]`. In your case `KS` is `keyof T` and `F<K>` is `[K, ...Parameters<T[K]>]`.  So you get this:

```
const useConfig =
<T extends Record<string, (...a: any) => null>>(features: T) =>
  (...args: { [K in keyof T]-?: [K, ...Parameters<T[K]>] }[keyof T][]): void =>
    void 0;
```

Let's see what happens when we call it:

```
const config = useConfig({
  attr: (prop: 'id', val: string) => null,
  style: (prop: 'font', val: 'arial') => null,
});

/* const config: (...args: (
  ["attr", "id", string] | ["style", "font", "arial"]
)[]) => void */
```

So this is exactly what you want.  Each argument passed into `config()` should be a tuple of type `["attr", "id", string]` or one of type `["style", "font", "arial"]`.  And you'll get the type checking you care about:

```
const t = config(
  ["attr", "id", "abc"], // okay
  ["style", 'font', "arial"], // okay
  ["attr", "font", ""] // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
);
```

---

Unfortunately that doesn't give you a great experience with IntelliSense and autocompletion.  This isn't really a problem with the above solution, but a limitation or missing feature of TypeScript, which is requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#38603](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38603).

We can work around this by having the compiler actually try to figure out which argument is a parameterization of which key.  That means if we call

```
const t = config(
  ["attr", "id", "abc"], 
  ["style", 'font', "arial"], 
  ["attr", "font", "abc"]
);
```

the compiler needs to know "the first key is `"attr"`, the second one is `"style"`, and third one is `"attr"`.  If you think of this as a tuple of keys `KS`, then here `KS` is `["attr", "style", "attr"]`.  And we need to represent the operation of turning the `KS` tuple into a tuple of parameterizations of each key in the tuple.  That is, we want to [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) the parameterization operation over the input tuple to get an output tuple.

*That* version looks like this:

```
const useConfig =
<T extends Record<string, (...a: any) => null>>(features: T) =>
  <KS extends Array<keyof T>>(...args: {
    [I in keyof KS]: [KS[I], ...Parameters<T[Extract<KS[I], keyof T>]>]
  }): void =>
    void 0;
```

It's a bit more involved; the compiler does map tuples to tuples with `{[I in keyof KS]: F<I>}` acting only on the numeric-like indices `I`, but it doesn't quite know that it's doing this inside the body of the mapped type, so it will balk if you treat `KS[I]` as if it's `keyof T`, (because "wHaT iF `I` iS somE arrAy meTHod nAme LIke `"push"`?  see [ms/TS#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995)).  We need to use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to convince the compiler that `KS[I]` can be treated as if it's assignable to `keyof T`.

Now when we call `config()`:

```
const t = config(
  ["attr", "id", "abc"], // okay
  ["style", 'font', "arial"], // okay
  ["attr", "font", "abc"], error!
  // -----> ~~~~ <---- error here
);

/* const config: <["attr", "style", "attr"]>(
    args_0: ["attr", "id", string], 
    args_1: ["style", "font", "arial"], 
    args_2: ["attr", "id", string]) => void 
*/
```

You can see that the compiler infers `["attr", "style", "attr"]` for `KS`, and then is unhappy specifically about the invalid `"font"` value in the `args_2` argument.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVYBLA9sJBvAUPkkhAB4yYBOALkvNlLQK5QQDC2AZugOZIC8RYkgA8AFRKlqEYABMoSAEoR6lWSMaV0wHgBokACgB0JkAC4kIYAE8AlAIB8SYEwA2rhw4OcIIak0poCzF7fgchYUMTIxBKHigLXCQAbQBpJG0kAGsIa0xOJDEAXQBaAH4LNP1ogAVY8AhpSihxNKKHIqQAX2ScvILi5KLbCwA3THRZRwjIpHHJpAAGAG5CYnpgRjouXgEkFnYdngMCSL9qSgsDGEpMGAsAckmH-VGQVwtNbR5Qpxd3XQzRjWVwQK43O6PTjYagvObvR6xdDvB6-ZxuVyA4hdWyrIQAegAVNtNrQNtweFdorF4ldkgAic6Uen6emTFlIL46ToAHxS9OBoI59OhwGowqR73pwyGaPmU0J+LWJK2tH4JIpBhmDKZwvZrJAACN4NL9Pj8UhMFkQNZtQLqCCIByHqLYQatFKimaLVabXbdazXcLpUhzSRKLdKABCGbmgB+CcTSeTiaEuMIXUIoEgsAQyAAksAfJQxEwYKC8EIyBQaCrmKwOEXdoJIuJJNI5AplKp1Fy9FFTBYrHZHOj3J5vL5-IEEoVfjNiCJUgBldsyeRIACCEZtIj6+UKE+pcVnp1mxGS+YyOH3BRXRUqK8vXqQtXqkCaLTEyQAolJKAg1BLsuz76Leh7tEUC7dCMcwTFMYTQcQ8pLHi6wMGSRx7AcjaamexBMuCtz3EgTyyHCbwfJyFzfGi-yYkCDqgkRkKka6FEIqRkquKio70ViMFoXWSBqhqvBapEOrUBceqyBKxqmqGPrWrakn2o6zrse6yKuIpYa+qpwhSTJgYwvJJpQcQ6YEsSGxbOSvAWCIxnMqygpOga0nMu0EmzDSUAAPqLJUjJebJHJ9i+0H+QFACMIXucKQbaZ6+jRSeAUAEwhQGSBsnJ+iRXK8FIEIioZkAA)